# What are derivations of raising and lowering operator function identities $af(a^{\dagger} a)=f(a a^{\dagger})a$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

What are the derivations of these identities? I do not know how they are called thus I can not find a reference.

> \begin{align}
> a f(a^\dagger a) & = f(a a^\dagger) a \\
> \sigma f(\sigma^\dagger \sigma) & = \sigma f(1)\\
> \sigma^\dagger f(\sigma^\dagger \sigma) & = \sigma^\dagger f(0)
> \end{align}

Source: https://cds.cern.ch/record/561046/files/0206116.pdf Page 4.

Comment: Hint: write $f$ as a power series of its argument and take commutators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important point: *functions of operators are always understood as their Taylor sums!* Thus, if $$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)x^n}{n!},$$ then
$$af(a^\dagger a) = a\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)(a^\dagger a)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)(a a^\dagger)^n}{n!}a=f(a^\dagger a)a.$$

I am not sure what $\sigma$ refers to here, but the Pauli matrices have important and easy to verify properties: $$\sigma_j^2=1, j=x,y,z,\\
\sigma_x\sigma_y = i\sigma_z \textrm{ and cyclic permutations of }x,y,z.$$

Comment: The $\sigma^{\dagger}$ and $\sigma$ are raising a lowering operators for a two-state system.

Comment: @Buzz Then they behave as regular fermion creation/annihilation operators. Anyhow, I've given the key to the solution - the forum policy prohibits me from solving it completely.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for help! I had this idea about expansion, but somehow I could not formulate it well in my head.